# discord.js TypeError: can not read property 'id' of undefined & Making a fail system

Tags: discord.js

So this command worked just a second ago then the next a error came out of nowhere. Is there a fix to this?

Here is the code

```js
run: async (client, message, args) => {
    const cooldown = cooldowns.get(message.author.id);
    if (cooldown) {
        const remaining = humanizeDuration(cooldown - Date.now(),{ units: ['m', 's'],round: true });
        let cEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setTitle("Slow down, cmon!")
        .setDescription(`You will be able to work in \`${remaining}\` just you wait!\n\nWhile you wait why not follow our [Twitter](https://twitter.com/switchoffical)`)
        return message.channel.send(cEmbed)
        .catch(console.error);

    } else {
        let member = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0]);
        let user = message.mentions.members.first()
        let targetuser = await db.fetch(`money_${user.id}`) // fetch mentioned users balance
        let author = await db.fetch(`money_${message.author.id}`) // fetch authors balance
        let uBalance = balance[member.id].balance;
        let TuBalance = balance[user.id].balance;
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1; // random number 200-1, you can change 200 to whatever you'd like
        let curBal = balance[message.author.id].balance 
        balance[message.author.id].balance = curBal + random;
        let crurBal = balance[message.author.id].balance 
        balance[user.id].balance = crurBal - random;

        if (!user) {
            return message.channel.send('Sorry, you forgot to mention somebody.')
            if (uBalance < 500) { // if the authors balance is less than 250, return this.
                return message.channel.send(':x: You need at least 500$ to rob somebody.')
            }

            if (TuBalance < 0) { // if mentioned user has 0 or less, it will return this.
                return message.channel.send(`:x: ${user.user.username} does not have anything to rob.`)
            }

            message.channel.send(`${message.author} you robbed ${user} and got away with ${random}!`)

            cooldowns.set(message.author.id, Date.now() + 900000);
            setTimeout(() => cooldowns.delete(message.author.id), 900000);

            db.subtract(`money_${user.id}`, random)
            db.add(`money_${message.author.id}`, random)
        } 
    }
}
```

The error that is made is

```
(node:7574) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
at Object.run (/app/commands/economy/rob.js:37:47)
at module.exports (/app/events/guild/message.js:10:33)
    at Client.emit (events.js:196:13)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/rbd/pnpm-volume/5936e237-314d-4884-9101-9ef8b43cdb53/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.2.0/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/rbd/pnpm-volume/5936e237-314d-4884-9101-9ef8b43cdb53/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.2.0/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/5936e237-314d-4884-9101-9ef8b43cdb53/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.2.0/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/5936e237-314d-4884-9101-9ef8b43cdb53/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.2.0/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/5936e237-314d-4884-9101-9ef8b43cdb53/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.2.0/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/5936e237-314d-4884-9101-9ef8b43cdb53/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.2.0/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:196:13)
(node:7574) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7574) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Now to my next question for the fail system I want it to subtract $500 away from the author and give the 500 to whom they were robbing from. I have the code but it broke the command and there is just too much going on in the code where the system will not fit that I have. SO I completely trashed the fail portion. For the fail rate it is pretty high and there is about a 10% chance you will actually rob someone. is there a efficient way to do this with the big code I have.

Comment: Could you paste the full error or say which line caused the error?

Comment: Okay I just edited where the error was. In case you can not figure it out where is says ```let author = await db.fetch(`money_${message.author.id}`)``` That is where the error is coming from I have no idea why because it worked before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues here :

### Issue 1:

By using

```
let user = message.mentions.members.first()`
```

The variable `user` can be undefined if there are no mentions in the message.

You were right to check for `!user`, however, you forgot to move the line just before :

```
let user = message.mentions.members.first()`
// [...]
balance[user.id].balance = crurBal - random;
if (!user) {
```

Should be :

```
let user = message.mentions.members.first()`
// [...]
if (!user) {
    balance[user.id].balance = crurBal - random;
```

### Issue 2:

Keep in mind that a message does not always have an author. A webhook message has no author, [as you can see in the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) with the return type being `?User` (`?` here means that it can also be null). [Here is the related code](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/structures/Message.js#L69).

So you also need to check for an author to the recieved message.